# An Identity of Vaughan

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

In chapter 3 of Vaughan's book on the Hardy–Littlewood method, he states the identity 
$$\sum_{X< y\leqslant n} \Lambda(y)e(\alpha y) + \sum_{X< x \leqslant n}\sum_{X<y\leqslant n/x}\sum_{\substack{d\mid x\\ d\leqslant X}}\mu(d)\,\Lambda(y)\,e(\alpha xy) = \sum_{d\leqslant X}\sum_{X<y\leqslant n/d}\sum_{z\leqslant n/(yd)}\mu(d)\,\Lambda(y)\,e(\alpha dyz),$$
where $\Lambda$ is the von Mangoldt function, $\mu$ is the Möbius function, and $e({}\cdot{}) = e^{2\pi i(\,\cdot\,)}$.

The justification given for this is the fact that $\sum_{d\mid x, d\leqslant X}\mu(d) = 1$ for $x=1$ and $0$ for $1<x\leqslant X$, but I can't seem to manipulate the LHS to obtain the RHS. I appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging the two sums on the left-hand side (after changing the order of the $x$ and $y$ summation in the second sum) gives

$$ \sum_{X<y\leq n} \Lambda(y)\left( e(\alpha y)+\sum_{X<x\leq n/y}e(\alpha xy)\sum_{\substack{d\mid x\\ d\leq X}} \mu(d)\right). $$

Using the identity you mention, we can write

$$ e(\alpha y) = \sum_{1\leq x\leq X}e(\alpha xy)\sum_{\substack{d\mid x\\ d\leq X}}\mu(d),$$

since every term vanishes except the $x=1$ term. Therefore the left-hand side is

$$ \sum_{X<y\leq n}\Lambda(y)\sum_{1\leq x\leq n/y} e(\alpha xy)\sum_{\substack{d\mid x\\ d\leq X}}\mu(d). $$

If we write $x=dz$, say, then this is 
$$ \sum_{X<y\leq n}\Lambda(y)\sum_{1\leq d\leq \min(n/y,X)}\sum_{z\leq n/yd} e(\alpha dyz)\mu(d). $$

Swapping the range of summation again so that $d$ is on the outside we get the right-hand side.